# Cythonize python modules to a different target directory

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to cythonize some python modules (on windows) and want the resulting .c files stored in a different directory.

I tried something like this:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
module_list = cythonize(r'C:\myproject\module.py', 
                        force=True,
                        build_dir=r'C:\myproject\compiled_modules')
```

The compilation is done but the file module.c is created in C:\myproject and not in C:\myproject\compiled_modules as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the `cythonize` function can be coerced into doing that. I would just use the command line:

```
/path/to/cython yourmod.py -o compiled_modules/yourmod.c
```

Edit:

This command can be called from a python script using the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["/path/to/cython", "yourmod.py", "-o", "compiled_modules/yourmod.c"])
```

Edit 2:

According to [this Sage developer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/m22o0kq_EfM/7m6SpgzYVVcJ), relocating the c/cpp files is not supported by cython, so it looks like either compiling from the command line or using a normal configuration and then moving the c/cpp files are your only options.

Comment: Ok Scott. Everything is fine with using the command line, but I really want to use a python script and process many files at once. Thanks!

Comment: Updated to show how to call the command line through the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Great Scott! Thank you for the confirmation that it is not supported. I'll try your suggestion with the subprocess model. Answer accepted. Thanks again!